# Whats the difference between virsh destroy and virsh undefine

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, virtual-machine

I am new to servers and vms wanted to know the difference between

```
virsh destroy
```

and

```
virsh undefine
```

Comment: why did you tag python to this? have you checked the manual pages for the comand? I found this on the net: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19053-01/ldoms.mgr10/820-3838-10/chapter3.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4):

> The `virsh destroy` command initiates an immediate ungraceful shutdown
>   and stops the specified guest virtual machine. Using `virsh destroy` can
>   corrupt guest virtual machine file systems. Use the `virsh destroy`
>   command only when the guest virtual machine is unresponsive. The `virsh
>   destroy` command with the `--graceful` option attempts to flush the cache
>   for the disk image file before powering off the virtual machine.

[`virsh delete` @ access.redhat.com](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-virsh-delete)

> The `virsh undefine` domain command **undefines** a domain. If domain is inactive, the
>   configuration is removed completely. If the domain is active
>   (running), it is converted to a `transient domain`. When the guest
>   virtual machine becomes inactive, the configuration is removed
>   completely.

[`virsh undefine` @ access.redhat.com](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-virsh-delete)

Answer (score 2):

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-virsh-delete

Undefine - undefines the configuration for the Virtual Machine. However, if there is any VM running with the configuration, the configuration is not removed immediately but is deffered till all the VM's with that configuration are removed. Imagine a configuration template that you are using to create your Virual Machine i.e. (Storage Required, Memory, CPU required etc). Once deleted you won't be able to create any new VM with that template.

> The virsh undefine domain [--managed-save] [storage] [--remove-all-storage] [--wipe-storage] [--snapshots-metadata] [--nvram] command undefines a domain.

Destory - Is as good as killing your virtual machine.

> The virsh destroy command initiates an immediate ungraceful shutdown and stops the specified guest virtual machine.